# Irreducibility for multivariate polynomial polynomial generated from sum of irreducible polynomial in one variable

Tags: polynomials

Could any tell me if a multivariate polynomial generated from the sum of irreducible single variable polynomial is irreducible?
For example, f(x)=x^2+2x+2, g(x)=x^2+3x+3, h(x)=x^3+2x^2+2x+2 all of them are irreducible, then what about f(x,y,z) = f(x)+g(y)+h(z)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(x^2+1)-(y^2+1)=(x+y)(x-y)$

Answer (score 13):

For two variables, see W. Feit,
  Some consequences of the classification of finite simple groups, in
  *The Santa Cruz Conference on Finite Groups*, Proc. Sympos.
  Pure Math. **37**, American Mathematical Society, Providence,
  RI, 1980, pp. 175-181. The result is the following. A polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$  is *indecomposable* if
  whenever $f(x)=r(s(x))$ for polynomials $r(x),s(x)$, then either
  $\deg r(x)=1$ or $\deg s(x)=1$. Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are
  nonconstant indecomposable polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that
  $f(x)-g(y)$ factors in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Then either $g(x)=f(ax+b)$ for some
  $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, or else
   $$ \deg f(x) = \deg g(x) = 7,\ 11,\ 13,\ 15,\ 21,\ \mathrm{or}\                 
     31. $$
  Moreover, this result is best possible in the sense that for
   $n= 7,11,13, 15, 21$, or $31$, there exist indecomposable polynomials
   $f(x)$, $g(x)$ of degree $n$ such that $f(x)\neq g(ax+b)$ and
   $f(x)-g(y)$ factors. The proof uses the classification of finite simple groups!

Comment: *The proof uses the classification of finite simple groups!* Simply amazing !